# Javascript loading order

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there a difference in loading order between these 2 approaches? Is there a best practice for this?

**Approach 1:**

HTML

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>test()</script>
```

test.js

```
function test() {
    alert("Hello World!")
}
```

**Approach 2:**

HTML

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

test.js

```
test()

function test() {
    alert("Hello World!")
}
```

Comment: Put all your scripts before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no major difference in performance respect you can choose any if performance is concern.

In first approach if `test.js` gets failed to load you will get an error method is not defined, while in second approach there will be no error.

So put check whenever you using the function for first approach that whether function is available or not.

or in jQuery you can put all your code in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){/*do stuff here*/});
```

it will make sure the javascript is loaded and the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it from a performance standpoint, this was my biggest concern. I was curious specifically if test() in approach 2 waits until DOM is loaded before executing.

Answer (score 0):

They both doing same thing; setting `window.test` to a function and executing that. In approach 1, since a browser execute scripts sequencially, when `test()` is called, `test` will be defined. In approach 2, since `test` is [bound](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5) before the code is executed, `test()` will be succeed.

I will prefer approach 2 over approach 1, since I can know where `test` is defined when calling `test`, and all JS code is in a separated file, not directly in an HTML file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your reasoning on preferred approach.

Answer (score -1):

No, they both are equal. Use any of them.